# Oracle for LBA halting on some input

Tags: turing-machines, computability, halting-problem

Assume we have an oracle that tells, given a linear bounded automaton, if there exists an input on which it halts.

Can we then solve the real halting problem (i.e. decide if a given Turing machine halts on a given input)?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine yes. The emptiness problem for context-sensitive grammars is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Computational_problems), presumably by a reduction from the halting problem.  Given the [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton#LBA_and_context-sensitive_languages) between [LBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton) and [context-sensitive grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language), this implies that the same should hold for your problem too.  I suggest you verify that this is correct by working through the proofs of these statements, to check that they indeed give an explicit reduction from the halting problem; assuming they do, you will have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do that. The basic idea is that from an arbitrary Turing machine $M$ we can produce an LBA $C$ which checks whether its input codes a valid sequence of configurations for $M$ starting with the starting state and the empty tape, and ending in a halting state. Now we have that $C$ will accept some input if and only if $M$ halts on the empty input.